# Adobe Photoshop: Is it possible to change the SAMPLE TEXT in the font preview?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I wanted to change the default font text in Adobe Photoshop CS6 - perhaps even have the font my actual selection. So if I have selected text on the document - it will automatically make that the "Sample text"

I noticed a similar plugin

http://www.fontshop.com/plugin/

However this is just an add shopping cart for their fonts.

Answer (score 1):

As a default behaviour, there is no way to show a preview of your text IN the font selection panel in Photoshop, nor am I aware of any plugins that allow you to do so.

The only thing I can recommend to make your life easier is to use the arrow keys to cycle through the fonts so you see them change instantly.